# after_save acting on association causes fatal: exception reentered

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have profile model that belongs to a user model, and the user has one profile. When I update the profile I want to update the user.name field. My code is as follows

```
Class Profile  < ApplicationRecord
after_save :update_user
belongs_to :user
private
    def update_user
      user = self.user
      return if user.nil?
      name = "#{first_name} #{middle_name} #{family_name}"
      user.update(name: name ) unless user.name == name
    end
```

When this is triggered, I get an infinite loop causing the error

```
Failure/Error: user.update(name: name )

 fatal:
   exception reentered
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have ActiveRecord callbacks in your user model which attempt to update your profile model record.  So you're likely getting into never-ending loop.

Try updating the user model using a method that doesn't invoke callbacks. `update_column` is a possibility in this case.

```
user.update_column(:name, name ) unless user.name == name
```

Comment: As far as I can see the user model has no callbacks that update the profile, but nevertheless your suggestion worked a treat, thank you.